# Behaviour of return variable in a Javascript function

Tags: javascript

This works, but I don't understand why:

```js
function hasUppercase(input) {
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i] === input[i].toUpperCase()) {
      return true
    } else { 
      return false
    }
  }
}

console.log(hasUppercase("no"));
console.log(hasUppercase("Yes"));
```

How come the 'true' for the 'Yes' beats all the falses?

Comment: The `return` statement exits the function immediately.

Comment: That function is not working. `hasUppercase("ayyLmao")` returns false.

Comment: Your function checks only the first letter of the word

Comment: No, it's not working. It might seem it worked because the first character (`input[0]`) you're testing for matches the case but take it off and you'll see for yourself

Answer (score 1):

For all characters, you could just return (early exit) if you have found one uppercase letter - in cases of lower case, you need to iterate to the end of the string.

```js
function hasUppercase(input) {
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i] === input[i].toUpperCase()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(hasUppercase("no"));
console.log(hasUppercase("Yes"));
console.log(hasUppercase("yeS"));
```

Comment: That's almost an exact copy of the answer I posted a few minutes earlier

Comment: It really makes a SIGNIFICANT difference

Comment: Thanks so much! Return causes the function to exit immediately, I didn't realise.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems are due to the `return false` statement, which makes function return on first non-uppercase character. The way it is constructed, it will always return after first character. Others already gave you solutions, I'll give you more concise way to achieve the same:

### ES2015 (ES6)

```js
const hasUpperCase = in => in.split('').some(c => c === c.toUpperCase());

// Demo:
console.log(hasUpperCase('no'));
console.log(hasUpperCase('yeS'));
```

### Previous versions

```js
function hasUpperCase(input) {
  return input.split('').some(function isCharUpperCase(char) {
    return char === char.toUpperCase();
  });
}

// Demo:
console.log(hasUpperCase('no'));
console.log(hasUpperCase('yeS'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This function checks only the first character of a given input. If the first character is in Uppercase then it returns true else it returns false. The function quits after first iteration.

So if the given input is like 'yEs' then it returns false. As it checks only the first character 'y' and exits.